# Prevent R in conda environment from running `~/.Rprofile`

Tags: r, conda

### Problem

I have a conda environment with an R installation. My issue is that the conda R will run `~/.Rprofile` during startup. This is breaking the expectation that conda environments are self-contained. Specifically, I am loading packages in my `~/.Rprofile` that are not installed in the conda R (I am using `require()`, so just warnings). The process works the following way:

> The first .Rprofile file found on the R startup search path is processed. The search path is (in order): (i) `Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER")`, (ii) `./.Rprofile`, and (iii) `~/.Rprofile`. [Source: `startup` package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/startup/vignettes/startup-intro.html)

### Goal

Ideally, I would like to alter the **third** path to a location within the environment directory and somehow do this in the environment yaml during setup, such that I can easily replicate the setup on another device. I realize that this might not work, so a solution that permanently sets `R_PROFILE_USER` to an environment-specific location would also be appreciated.

#### Edit:

Since I am using R through `rpy2` I don't think I can use the `--no-init-file` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from  `?.Rprofile`, which invokes the man page for `Startup`,

> unless --no-init-file was given, R searches for a user profile, a file
> of R code. The path of this file can be specified by the
> R_PROFILE_USER environment variable (and tilde expansion will be
> performed). If this is unset, a file called ‘.Rprofile’ is searched
> for in the current directory or in the user's home directory (in that
> order). The user profile file is sourced into the workspace.

Comment: Thanks, I had also come that far in the documentation. That does not solve my issue where a conda `environment.yaml` is supposed to set up an environment that works the same way on 2 different systems

Comment: @shs  In that case, I suspect you'll have to write your `environment.yaml` file so that it tests for the  target environment and executes a branch based on the result

Comment: I've found that I can set environment variables trough `conda env config vars set my_var=value`. Conda does export that through `conda env export` into yaml. Except since I'll also need to create an empty .Rprofile file, I'll just have to write a bash script that creates the conda environment from the yaml and the `.Rprofile` and then sets the variable to the location of the file. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bash script to solve this issue. Run it in the project directory containing the `environment.yml`. It prompts for a name of the newly created conda environment, then creates and activates it. Subsequently an empty `.Rprofile` is created in the environment directory and `R_PROFILE_USER` is set to this location. Finally, the environment is reactivated for the change to take effect. Thus, any time R is run from this environment, the newly created `.Rprofile` is used.

It should be noted that an `.Rprofile` in `R_PROFILE_USER` takes precedence over an `.Rprofile` in the project directory. This might lead to confusion if the user wants to create use such a file and is unaware of the setup.

```bash
echo What name do you want to give to the conda environment?
read input
conda env create -n $input -f environment.yml
conda activate $input
touch $CONDA_PREFIX/.Rprofile
conda env config vars set R_PROFILE_USER=$CONDA_PREFIX
conda activate $input
```